# Is it possible to implement filters with multiple predicates?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm having trouble figuring out how to work with multiple predicates in `slick`.

For a simple example, imagine a SQL style AND filter where a user matches a specified first and last name:

```
def getByName(first: String, last: String) = {
  users // TableQuery[Users]
    .filter(_.userFirstName === first)
    .filter(_.userLastName === last)
    .result
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic (and more performant) implementation of complex filters with multiple predicates in `slick` or am I taking the wrong approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
def getByName(first: String, last: String) = {
  users
    .filter(user => user.userFirstName === first && user.userLastName === last)
    .result
}
```